# What is the best way to pass in padding about its children in Jetpack Compose @Composable functions

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

ok so I am trying to write a composable function that has a default padding but I found that with a default modifier parameter it gives me this warning: [image]

I understand the reason is that if we want to actually passin some non-default modifier then it would be overridden, but what would be the best way to add such constraint from parent Composables to its children?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make padding another argument

```
@Composable
fun Component(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(top = 16.dp),
) {
    Box(modifier = modifier.padding(contentPadding)) {}
}
```